# PHP Function Variable Pass Through

Tags: php, sql

Rusty, just simply trying to pass stuff through parameters. What am I doing wrong?

```
//Insert into DB
function insert(x,y,z)
mysql_query("INSERT INTO x (y)
VALUES ('z')");


insert("test","name","Tyler");
```

Comment: You're doing wrong everything. Have you read this: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php ?

Comment: You forgot to use `$` to sinalize the variables and curly braces in the function scope

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: What error messages do you get when you try to run the code you posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function insert($x,$y,$z){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$x." (".$y.") VALUES ('".$z."')");
}
insert("test","name","Tyler");
```

Comment: Much more confusing than I remember, thanks! Why the dots around the variables?

Comment: `.` concatenates the variables with your string.  Since you are using double-quotes, concatenation is not necessary and the variables can be placed directly into the string and will be evaluated correctly.

Comment: The dot is PHP's string concatenation operator.  You could also do like `"INSERT INTO $x ($y) VALUES ('$z')"` if you wanted, but some people don't like that for some reason.  Though i'd argue if they don't like it, they shouldn't be sticking all their strings in double quotes...cause then interpolation will only happen when you *don't* want it to. :P

Comment: yeah, i have that habit and like it being colored in editors.

Comment: What would be the new way to retrieve data from sqldatabase and turn it into text and echo? Use to be hell.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are referencing the variable correctly via `$`:

```
//Insert into DB
function insert($x, $y, $z)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $x ($y) VALUES ('$z')");
}


insert("test","name","Tyler");
```

Comment: Yea, I think I was doing it kind of javascripty . Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  It's helpful that you always debug your code to ensure that the desired result is occurring properly.

Comment: The purpose of debugging is not always to identify bugs.  [`Debugging`](http://robzu.com/how-to-be-a-programmer/) in itself means to remove errors and *to see into the execution of a program by examining it*.  It is the second part that I was referring to.

Comment: What would be the new way to retrieve data from sqldatabase and turn it into text and echo? Use to be hell.